# jpa query to update many to one association

Tags: jpa, jpql

Is possible to create a query to update a field that is part of a relationship?  I wont update the childs, i just want to update the field into the association....

I tried but I get the error: can not navigate association field

How could I do this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a query.

Get the object that represents the relationship, modify the values that you need and then persist it.

Comment: Thanks 4 answer.. alredy do something like this: em.merge(someObject); em.flush(); em.refresh(someObject); but i got the next error: "Can not refresh not managed object", in fact "someObject" is an object get it with em.find and it contains the changes that i need